# sort the format "mm/dd/yyyy-mm/dd/yyyy" based on month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
1/1/2020 - 3/31/2020
4/1/2020 - 6/31/2020
1/1/2019 - 3/31/2019
1/1/2021 - 3/31/2021
4/1/2021 - 6/31/2021
```

"I want to sort this format into"

```
1/1/2019 - 3/31/2019
1/1/2020 - 3/31/2020
4/1/2020 - 6/31/2020
1/1/2021 - 3/31/2021
4/1/2021 - 6/31/2021
```

sort this based on the month  in pandas python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to use casting:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''
col1,col2
1/1/2020 - 3/31/2020,1
4/1/2020 - 6/29/2020,2
1/1/2019 - 3/31/2019,3
1/1/2021 - 3/31/2021,4
11/1/2021 - 6/29/2021,5
10/1/2021 - 6/29/2021,6
4/11/2021 - 6/29/2021,7
9/1/2020 - 6/29/2020,8
8/1/2020 - 6/29/2020,9
4/13/2021 - 6/29/2021,10
4/10/2021 - 6/29/2021,11
4/1/2021 - 6/29/2021,12
4/1/2021 - 6/25/2021,13
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
print(df)

# split dates
df[['start', 'end']] = df['col1'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)

# cast
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

# sort by start and end dates
df.sort_values(by=['start', 'end'], inplace=True)

print(df[['col1', 'col2']])
```